# formBuilder Save or Copy HTML are not working

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, formbuilder

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          media="screen"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.1/jquery.rateyo.min.css"
        />
    
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
        />
        <title>jQuery formBuilder/formRender Demo</title>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <header class="demo-header">
          <label for="toggleBootstrap">Toggle Bootstrap <input type="checkbox" id="toggleBootstrap"/></label>
          <div>
            dataType:
            <label>XML <input type="radio" name="demo-dataType" value="xml" class="demo-dataType"/></label
            ><label>JSON <input type="radio" name="demo-dataType" value="json" class="demo-dataType"/></label>
          </div>
          <div>
            Language:
            <select id="setLanguage">
              <% _.forEach(htmlWebpackPlugin.options.langFiles, function(langFile) { %>
              <option value="<%- langFile.locale %>"><%- langFile.nativeName %></option>
              <% }); %>
            </select>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
          <h1 class="formbuilder-title">
            jQuery formBuilder -
            <button class="editForm">Render</button>
          </h1>
          <h1 class="formrender-title">
            jQuery formRender -
            <button class="editForm">Edit</button>
          </h1>
          <div class="build-wrap"></div>
          <form class="render-wrap"></form>
          <div class="action-buttons formbuilder-actions">
            <h2>Actions</h2>
            <table id="action-api" class="api-table"></table>
            <div id="toggleEdit">
              <button class="trigger">Toggle Field Edit</button>
              <input type="text" placeholder="current field id" class="current-field-id" />
            </div>
            <div id="removeField">
              <button class="trigger">Remove Field</button>
              <input type="text" placeholder="current field id" class="current-field-id" />
            </div>
            <div id="setData">
              <button class="trigger">Set Form Data</button>
              <textarea id="set-form-data-value">
                [
                  {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Full Name",
                    "subtype": "text",
                    "className": "form-control",
                    "name": "text-1476748004559"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Occupation",
                    "className": "form-control",
                    "name": "select-1476748006618",
                    "values": [
                      {
                        "label": "Street Sweeper",
                        "value": "option-1",
                        "selected": true
                      },
                      {
                        "label": "Moth Man",
                        "value": "option-2"
                      },
                      {
                        "label": "Chemist",
                        "value": "option-3"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "textarea",
                    "label": "Short Bio",
                    "rows": "5",
                    "className": "form-control",
                    "name": "textarea-1476748007461"
                  }
                ]</textarea
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="action-buttons formrender-actions">
            <h2>Actions</h2>
            <button id="loadUserForm" type="button">Load User Form</button>
            <button id="showUserData" type="button">Show User Data</button>
            <button id="renderUserForm" type="button">Render User Form</button>
            <button id="getHTML" type="button">Get HTML</button>
            <button id="clearUserForm" type="button">Clear Form</button>
            <button id="testSubmit" type="submit">Test Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formbuilder-options"></div>
        <script src="https://kevinchappell.github.io/formBuilder/assets/js/vendor.js"></script>
    
        <script src="https://kevinchappell.github.io/formBuilder/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kevinchappell.github.io/formBuilder/assets/js/form-render.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kevinchappell.github.io/formBuilder/assets/js/demo.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.3.1/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
    
        <script>
          jQuery(function($) {
            $(document.getElementById('fb-editor')).formBuilder();
          });
        </script>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

Please help formBuilder Save or Copy HTML are not working. I am using https://formbuilder.online/ locally but there is some issue once I clicked on save nothing happens. I want to save form in HTML code or Copy HTML code as it is happening in https://formbuilder.online/ this link.

Please someone help me I am searching everywhere but I didn't find any demo with save is working.

Let me show some more demo link but there is also Save is not working.

https://kevinchappell.github.io/formBuilder/

https://codepen.io/kevinchappell/pen/Vedrqr

Please check above link there is also issue of Save in HTML (Get HTML).

Comment: have you solved your case @Sushil...?

Comment: Iam too facing this issue,Did u manage to solve it?